# Table View not showing titles

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

I'm developing my project on swift and create a simple table view with one cell, then i created a label, but it's not showing. What's the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you trying to search for tutorial at first? I wish you would look at this tutorial: http://www.codingexplorer.com/getting-started-uitableview-swift/

Comment: you are probabl dequeuing wrong cell, but for more, as Reming said, we need to see the code

Answer (score 0):

If you're transitioning back to the TableView from another ViewController, try updating on the main thread in ViewDidAppear.

Making sure you're dequeuing the correct cell is also another potential fall, as mentioned above.

Hard to help without code though, hope this helps.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```